# Linux - Handle stack overflow and buffer overflow with sigaction

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault, stack-trace, buffer-overflow

sigaction works only with some SIGSEGV scenarios.
When I try to handle a SIGSEGV that was caused via a buffer overflow or stack overflow, the handler is never called.
But when other scenarios that cause SIGSEGV, it does work.

**Works**:

```
void Foo2(std::string str)
{
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    *ptr = 42;  // Dereferencing nullptr causes SIGSEGV
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
        
void Foo1(std::string str)
{
    Foo2(str + "1");
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
        
void handler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    std::cout << "+++++++" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    int size = 36384;
    stack_t ss;
    ss.ss_sp = malloc(size);
    if (ss.ss_sp == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate stack");
        exit(1);
    }
    ss.ss_size = size;
    ss.ss_flags = 0;

    if (sigaltstack(&ss, NULL) == -1) 
    {
        perror("sigaltstack");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sigaction act = { 0 };
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_ONSTACK;
    act.sa_sigaction = &handler;
    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, NULL) == -1) 
    {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Foo1("a");
}
    
**Output**: 

    +++++++

**But when I cause stack overflow, it doesn't work:**

    // All other code is the same as above
    void Foo2(std::string str)
    {
        Foo1(str + "2");
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
```

**Output**:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Same when causing a buffer overflow**:

```
void Foo2(std::string str)
{
    char buffer[10];
    std::strcpy(buffer, "This string is too long for the buffer.");
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

**Buffer overflow output**:

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**So my questions are**:

1. Why doesn't the handler handle these stack overflow and buffer overflow like the first example? they all cause SIGSEGV.
2. How can I handle any case of SIGSEGV and print the stack trace with boost::stacktrace, crashpad or any other API.

Stats: C++ 17, boost 1.82.0.

Comment: 1. When a stack overflow occurs, there's no stack memory available for running your handler. 2. This is not a segmentation fault, no signal is raised, it's just abort() or terminate().

Comment: It is unusual you are trying to do some actions when those things happens. Can you explain why you are trying to do that? What is actual goal? Also note that all of this is undefined behavior which means anything can happen, you are in nasal daemons world.

Comment: Also a buffer overrun will not always trigger an access violation because it is overwriting some other part of the heap (which is accessible memory)

Comment: An easier approach to find the underlying problem so that you can fix both stack overflows and buffer overflows in your code may be to compile the program with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined`. It usually becomes clear where the problems are when you run the program when compiled with those options.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick and great replies, Much appreciated! 
@MarekR - I am trying to print the stack trace using boost::stacktrace in my handler. However, my handler isn't always called.

Comment: Ok so basically you are implementing your own "crash reporter". I would recommend use some ready solution or at least take a look how others did that. For example google breakpad.

Comment: Aren't these events caught if you compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` as I proposed earlier? If they are, you don't have to do _anything_ to get the report needed to find your bugs.

Comment: Hey @TedLyngmo.
I tried it and unfortunately it didn't work. I added these to my long g++ command line.
Any other suggestions will be gladly received

Comment: @ArielSilver Can you show a small example of code causing stack overflow or buffer overflow that your signal handler is capable of catching which `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` is not capable of catching?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Great question. Unfortunately the issue is that I can't catch any stack overflow or buffer overflow. I tried your suggestion but it didn't report any data on the overflows... The output was exactly the same as the previous ones. However when I tried to dereference a nullptr, it did add extra data!

Comment: @ArielSilver That's so odd becuase it catches [stack overflow](https://godbolt.org/z/4a6svaM33), [stack buffer overflow](https://godbolt.org/z/qsP6G5dGh) and [heap buffer overflow](https://godbolt.org/z/Ejh5jhdqM) for me. Can you show an example of a small program where you know you have any of these problems that the sanitizers did not catch?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I really appreciate you help! You can see my full code + my GCC command in: https://codeshare.io/ForTed

Comment: @ArielSilver You have a space in `-fsanitize=address, undefined` so I don't see how you could have compiled that. If I remove that space and add the missing header `#include <cstring>`, it compiles and then the sanitizer _does_ find the `stack-buffer-overflow`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/PE7jPaT7T)  - I had to replace `-lbacktrace` (which isn't a boost library) with `-lboost_stacktrace_basic` though. Also, the `-std=c11` flag is pointless and will be dropped. You can't combile language options like that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo My bad on the space. Actually I added it just before sending you the code example as I was reordering the GCC command and accidently added it. However, I see it works in your link, but locally it still doesn't work. I guess I have a problem in my machine. Thanks for the help any way!

Comment: @ArielSilver What OS and `g++ --version` are you using locally?

Answer (score 0):

A stack overflow will cause a second SIGSEGV when trying to run the handler as the stack is full.  This second SIGSEGV won't be caught as the handler is disabled while it is running, so kills the process before anything else happens.

A buffer overflow generally won't cause a SIGSEGV at all (unless you've arranged for an unmapped page after the buffer).  Instead, it will overwrite whatever is after the buffer -- in your case a stack guard used to detect stack smashing.

If you want to able to catch stack overflows, you'll need to arrange for an alternate stack for the signal handler.  You do this by setting up an alternate signal stack with `sigaltstack`, and setting the `SA_ONSTACK` flag to sigaction.

If you want to be able to catch buffer overflows, it is much harder.  For a large buffer, you can use mmap to allocate it instead of malloc and ensure that it is followed by an invalid page, but that is a fair amount of work, and requires that the buffer be a multiple of the page size.

Comment: Hey Chris. Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my issue.
I updated the code in my question to the one that uses sigaltstack. However the behavior is exactly the same. Can you please tell me if I'm missing something ?

Comment: Post an example that actually fails -- when I take your code and fix it to actually compile (and trigger a stack overflow) it works just fine.

Comment: Hey Chris. I am extremely happy to hear it works for you! The code I posted in my question is the that actually fails. Of course it misses the #includes and Foo1() declaration, but after adding those it compiles. Any chance you can send me the code that worked for you? It will really be a life saver. You can use https://codeshare.io/ArielSilver or any other way. (You will see there my full code)

Comment: I copied the code I used to your buffer -- bascially just your code with added headers and forward declaration.